# Split several images into pieces and merge them

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I'm curious if there is a program or method which allows you to split several images into equal pieces and merge them into one image afterwards.

For example:
I have 10 images from a timelapse recording.
The goal is to select all 10 images, cut them into equal pieces and merge them into one image (1st slice from image 1, 2nd slice from picture 2 ...)

In the end I would like to have one image consisting of 10 different slices from 10 different images.

There are ways to reach this result manually, but its really frustrating cutting merging 100 images.

I hope you got my intention :D

Comment: I thought I had a handle on this, but the more I read this question, the more confusing it gets. Could you add some clarification on what the starting point is and what an example image or description of  what the end result to be. Simply. There's like a probably a kazillion ways to cut an image and merge multiple images. Like cut in 100 pieces equally. Or all images merged vertically or partially on top of each other... Or maybe even marged into a single pdf file with multiple pages.

Comment: Do you want to do a time lapse collage like this? https://i.pinimg.com/736x/e5/1b/35/e51b35d2c1f41dd52dc03cf0bd207d59.jpg

Comment: Okay, I see that there is some confusion.
The result should be ONE image
10 different images = 10 different slices.
Another example: I take one image every hour for one day. The result should be an image of 24 slices where every slice represents 1 hour of the day.  Does this help?

Comment: @Luciano - YES!! Exactly. Do you know a program do achieve this?

Comment: I must've been in a hurry when I wrote that comment. That's pretty bad even for me. Somewhat understandable, but parts of it are like the insane ramblings of a lunatic.

Comment: @Joonas I find it very valuable that you add a comment with a rectification. I don't understand the imperious need of some to put sarcastic comments on each question. I don't flag them for not getting into arguments, but they are very tiring.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a workaround using the script of [this answer](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/26216/120647). This example is placing the ten images in a 5 x 2 collage, which is more difficult, it can be easily done in a single row of ten modules.

Before playing the script:

- Set all images at the same size
- I recommend making a copy in another folder and rename them as 01.jpg, 02.jpg, etc.
- At the script

  - set the `var cellWidth` = to the cell with, in this example: 1/5 of the image width
  - set the `var cellHeight` = to the cell height, in this example: 1/2 of the image height
  - set the `var xOffset` and `var yOffset` = 0
- Open all images and play the script to each of them

The result is 10 modules files of each image, renamed in this order:

[image: order]

With this, from **menu File** > **Automate** > **Contact Sheet**

- Choose the files following the previous scheme order: the odd of each of the first five images in order, the pairs of the remaining images in order
- Set the document width and height the same as the original image
- Set the columns = 5 and the rows = 2

Tested with ten random images

[image: Collage]